# How do I register a model that is already registered in admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I am trying to change the field order in the admin of a field in a django package (rest framework)

I define a new adminmanager, but get a 'Model Already Registered' Error. Surely there must be a way to do it?

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
class AuthTokenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'key',)


admin.site.register(Token, AuthTokenAdmin)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason this error occurs is, the class `Token` has already been [registered with an admin class like this](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/admin.py#L11):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class TokenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('key', 'user', 'created')
    fields = ('user',)
    ordering = ('-created',)


admin.site.register(Token, TokenAdmin)
```

To change this, you first need to `unregister` the old admin registration against the given class, and then register the new one.

Try this:

```
admin.site.unregister(Token) #First unregister the old class
admin.site.register(Token, AuthTokenAdmin) #Then register the new class
```

Comment: I end up in some wired loop: without: `admin.site.unregister(Token)` I got  `The model Token is already registered
` with I got `The model Token is not registered`. I am using django dashboard, where I register:  'rest_framework.authtoken.Token',

Comment: Hi @andi your problem could be the order of the apps in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Keep your custom apps below third party apps so that `unregister` is called on an already registered model.